# How to make one node move close or away from another node depending on a value?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to be able to have a static node and a dynamic node. I want the dynamic node to move closer or further away from the static node depending on a value.

For example, if the value is closer to 1000 I want the dynamic node to move closer to the static node and if the value is closer to 100 I want the dynamic node to move further away from the static node.

I am using SceneKit, would I apply physics bodies the the two node? If so how?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is very broad. Have you tried to write any code to do this?

Comment: No I have not. I didn’t know where to begin. To go into more detail, I want to be able to have one sphere node (static) on a wall (in my SceneKit model) and one sphere that is dynamic that will be on the floor (in my SceneKit model) I then want the dynamic sphere node to move in response to a numerical value. So if the number is closer too 1000 I want the dynamic sphere node to move closer to the static sphere node on the wall and if the number is closer to 100 I want the dynamic sphere node to move away from the static sphere node on the wall.

Comment: Well since you know about SceneKit, and think physics is involved, why don't you try something out?

Comment: Could you help to point me in the right direction? I really need to figure this out for my project to be complete. Any help is greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think I would use the collision aspect because my nodes are not meant to collide with each other.